# Persistence xml 2 tables

Tags: xml, hibernate, jpa

I currently have the following persistence xml file, I am using it to create two databases, one containing a table of users (mapped from a java entity class) and the other to map a table of monsters (as above).

I am totally new to JPA, this is the first time I've used it and so far I have managed to cobble the following xml code together:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="monsters" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>databaseManagement.Monster</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:monsters"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  <persistence-unit name="users" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>databaseManagement.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:users"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However, what I want is the user and monster tables to be two tables in a single database rather than two tables in two separate databases as they currently are, however I am not sure how to do this.

Thanks a lot, I am really quite stuck as to how this is accomplished, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very simple, you have to remove a **persistent-unit** and add the delete class in the remaining unit.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="monsters" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>databaseManagement.Monster</class>
    <class>databaseManagement.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:monsters"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Look here for more [example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration)